# Memory organisation with inheritence and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, memory

Hello here is the code

```
class Msg {
public:
    int info1;
    int info2;
    char* msg;
};

class SpeMsg : public Msg {
public:
    struct speInfos {
        int speInfo1;
        int speInfo2;
    };
    speInfos spe;
};

int main()
{
    SpeMsg* sm = new SpeMsg();
    sm->info1 = 5;
    sm->info2 = 10;
    sm->spe.speInfo1 = 15;
    sm->spe.speInfo2 = 20;
    sm->msg = new char[sizeof("25")];
    memcpy(sm->msg, "25", sizeof("25"));
    uint8_t * payload = (uint8_t*)sm;
    SpeMsg::speInfos* sI = &sm->spe;

    cout << "Info 1 : " << &sm->info1 << endl;
    cout << "Info 2 : " <<&sm->info2 << endl;
    cout << "msg : " <<&sm->msg << endl;
    
    cout << "pointing to : " <<(void *)sm->msg << endl;
    cout << "SpeInfo1 : " <<&sm->spe.speInfo1 << endl;
    cout << "SpeInfo2 : " <<&sm->spe.speInfo2 << endl;

    
    delete sm->msg;
    delete sm;
    return 0;
}
```

I am here trying to understand what's done in memory from the constructor to the print of the address.

The result here is

Info 1 : 0x1515eb0

Info 2 : 0x1515eb4

msg : 0x1515eb8

pointing to : 0x1515ed0

SpeInfo1 : 0x1515ec0

SpeInfo2 : 0x1515ec4

I am wandering why my msg address is 0x1515ed0 and not 0x1515ec8 because SpeInfo2 is an int ?
Is this just random or should i understand something ?

Comment: `msg` is pointing to some memory area you allocated with `new char[]`. It will not be related to any other of your structures.

Comment: @OP `sm->msg = new char[sizeof("25")];` -- Where does `new[]` get its memory?

Comment: Okay so it's pure random ?

Comment: @Kaldir no, it's not pure random, but you cannot draw any conclusions from memory addresses the systems allocates for you.

Comment: @Kaldir Unpredictable is more accurate than random. Not much in your computer is random.

Comment: What should i do to have a memory alignement then with this inheritence ? some placement new ?

Comment: @Kaldir -- When you used `new[]` you asked for memory from the free-store.  Are you aware of that?  If you are, where is the memory from the free-store located?   The address of the pointer, you see there is nothing "strange" about it.  But where the pointer *points to*, that is a totally different story.

Comment: @Kaldir why do you care about alignement?

Comment: Normally no special action is required for alignment and I don't see any problem here. Why do you think it is an issue? Only by knowing that can anyone give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For members of a struct or class, the only rule is that later members will have a higher address. That's it! There is no rule about how *much* higher the address must be (except to avoid overlap). The compiler is allowed to add space inbetween the members ("padding").

For allocations with `new` and for variables declared separately, you get whatever address the compiler has available. There is no order required.

Answer (score -1):

It is not because of what the constructor does. It is because you are calling the `new` operator. You cannot expect any memory alignment if you do that.

If you want memory alignment, try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <boost/static_string.hpp>

constexpr auto MaxMsgSize = 256;
using MsgText = boost::static_string<MaxMsgSize>;

class Msg 
{
public:
    int info1;
    int info2;
    MsgText msg;
};

class SpeMsg : public Msg {
public:
    struct speInfos {
        int speInfo1;
        int speInfo2;
    };
    speInfos spe;
};

int main()
{
    auto sm = SpeMsg{};
    sm.info1 = 5;
    sm.info2 = 10;
    sm.spe.speInfo1 = 15;
    sm.spe.speInfo2 = 20;

    sm.msg = "25";
    const SpeMsg::speInfos& sI = sm.spe;

    std::cout << "Info 1 : " << &sm.info1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Info 2 : " << &sm.info2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "msg : " << &sm.msg << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "pointing to : " << &sm.msg << std::endl;
    std::cout << "SpeInfo1 : " << &sm.spe.speInfo1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "SpeInfo2 : " << &sm.spe.speInfo2 << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
Info 1 : 0x7ffd60e7b148
Info 2 : 0x7ffd60e7b14c
msg : 0x7ffd60e7b150
pointing to : 0x7ffd60e7b150
SpeInfo1 : 0x7ffd60e7b254
SpeInfo2 : 0x7ffd60e7b258
```

Comment: What should i do to have a memory alignement then with this inheritence ?

Comment: You can do inheritance if you really need it also without using the new operator (tbh I do not think you really need inheritance in this case: just use composition). I will edit my answer.